# Using Python3, need to insert a new string into a list and, if found, need to append suffix and increase counter by 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of fruit names that I need to keep as unique string identifiers. Here's an example:

`fruit_names = ['banana_001','apple_001','banana_002']`

There is also a function that acts on `fruit_names` and adds a new fruit to the list. If it finds the fruit on this list, it increments the ID after the underscore by 1. If it doesn't find the fruit at all, it starts the naming at 1:

```
>>>fruits.add(fruit_names,'apple')
>>>fruits.add(fruit_names,'orange')
>>>print(fruit_names)
['banana_001', 'apple_001', 'banana_002', 'apple_002', 'orange_001']
```

I have a hacky implementation I am not happy with for `fruits.add()` and was wondering if there's a super simple way of accomplishing the above that I may be missing.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your implementation.

Comment: A dictionary would be a simpler implementation: `{'banana': 2, 'apple': 2, 'orange': 1}`

Comment: Each fruit needs to have a unique ID that is also a string, unfortunately. I then take this list of 'fruit,' and I pass it to an API that uses the strings in that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions presented by Ajax1234 are pretty good, but they would be slow if you have a vary large list to go through. That's because each addition takes `O(N)` time, since it needs to recount the number of times that the new fruit has appeared so far in the list. If instead you kept track of the count as you go using a dictionary, it can be much more efficient (amortized `O(1)` time per addition).

```
class FruitList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fruits = []
        self.counts = {}

    def add(self, fruit):
        self.counts[fruit] = count = self.counts.get(fruit, 0) + 1
        self.fruits.append(f"{fruit}_{count:03d}")

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.fruits)
```

Here's an example of it in action using one-character fruit names (just because it's easy to generate them):

```
>>> fl = FruitList()
>>> for f in 'abcabbaabc':
    fl.add(f)

>>> fl
['a_001', 'b_001', 'c_001', 'a_002', 'b_002', 'b_003', 'a_003', 'a_004', 'b_004', 'c_002']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function `_add`:

```
def _add(_l:list, _item:str) -> list:
  return _l+[_item +'_'+str(sum(c.split('_')[0] == _item for c in _l)+1).zfill(3)]

fruit_names = ['banana_001','apple_001','banana_002']
for i in ['banana', 'apple', 'pear']:
  fruit_names = _add(fruit_names, i)
```

Output:

```
['banana_001', 'apple_001', 'banana_002', 'banana_003', 'apple_002', 'pear_001']
```

Edit: if you wish to treat `add` as a method, you can create a linked-list:

```
class Fruits:
   def __init__(self, _val = None, _c = None):
     self.head, self._next = _val if _val is None else f'{_val}_{str(_c).zfill(3)}', None
   def __str__(self):
     return self.head if self._next is None else f'{self.head}, {str(self._next)}'
   def __repr__(self):
      return f'[{str(self)}]'
   def add(self, fruit, _count = 1):
     if self.head is None:
         self.head = f'{fruit}_{str(_count).zfill(3)}'
     else:
         getattr(self._next, 'add', lambda x, y:setattr(self, '_next', Fruits(x, y)))(fruit, _count+(self.head.split('_')[0] == fruit))

fruits = Fruits()
for i in ['banana','apple','banana', 'peach', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana']:
  fruits.add(i)
```

Output:

```
[banana_001, apple_001, banana_002, peach_001, orange_001, banana_003, apple_002, banana_004]
```